# How can I text on a single line only using HTML and inline CSS?

Tags: html, css, text, formatting, inline

I'm currently redesigning a company's email signature and am having trouble with the phone and fax numbers running over more than one line when viewed on an iPhone.
The problem is that this information is displayed in a single cell table like so:

T: +44 (0)208 1234 1234
F: +44 (0)208 1234 1234
address line 1
address line 2
address line 3

but the numbers end up spilling over when viewed on a smart phone like this:

T: 44 (0)208 1234
1234
F: 44 (0)208 1234
1234

I want to keep each line after the other, not have big line breaks like the ones you get with paragraph and div tags or even separate table data (even with no spacing or padding) so am having problems adding attributes without adding unwanted spacing between each line.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Show us some code.  Preferably just the table HTML and CSS

Comment: `white-space: nowrap` CSS property from the sounds of things.

Comment: Also what kind of viewport are you using, i think that the table is to small on the iphone for the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrapping is caused by some limitation on the width of the cell, in your code or by the context or device. You can try to prevent wrapping in several ways: `<td nowrap>...</td>` or `<td><nobr>...</nobr></td>` or `<td style="white-space: nowrap">...</td>`. However, this would probably mean that the cell tries to grow beyond the limitations, which may fail or cause overflow (which may mean truncation of content or horizontal scrollbar). This all depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

use `white-space: nowrap`

example here http://jsfiddle.net/83e9C/

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a fixed width for one or more of the elements.